# How do I remove a border from a pseudo element when the parent element has one?

Tags: html, css

**Explanation:**

I modified a CodePen I found online and now it looks like this.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQqdPq

As you can see on the leftmost side of the table, the shadow shows which is good, but it has the same border as its parents.

[image]

I've tried putting `border: 0px;` in pseudo elements but this doesn't seem to do anything.

**Question:**

Can I remove the border from the shadow you see on the left and righthandside of the table? Ideally I'd like the border to still overlay the shadows inside, but if this is too fiddly then I can live without that.

**Code Excerpt:**

Here is the CSS in question

```
.shadow {
  position: relative;
} 
.shadow:before {
  box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
}
.shadow:after {
  box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `border: 0;` to the pseudo-elements?

Comment: This isn’t a border _on_ the pseudo elements, so trying to remove border _from_ the pseudo elements of course achieves nothing. Besides that, I am not really sure what you are actually asking about here. Do you want to remove the outer borders from the first an last table cell? Well then do that. Or do you mean the horizontal small white line that cuts into the shadows?

Comment: Hi Cbroe. I'd like to maintain the borders on all existing cells. It is just the little lines coming off the sides of the table which I'd like to get rid of. I'll update my answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a border. That's a 1px gap between the pseudo elements which looks like a border of 1px.

You can fix it in many ways, the way I would do it is to increase the height of the pseudo element by 1px to cover the gap.

```
.shadow:before {
    height: calc(100% + 1px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% + 1px);// (optional) for older webkit browsers
    height: -moz-calc(100% + 1px);// (optional) for older firefox browsers
}
```

same thing for the ones on the right `.shadow:after`.

If you're interested, you can [learn more about calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc).